# Наложение водяного знака на загружаемое изображение

Tags: php

Есть код загрузки изображения на сервер:

```
if (@$_REQUEST['Upload']) { 
$data = $_FILES['file']; 
$tmp = $data['tmp_name']; 
if (@file_exists($tmp)) { 
$info = @getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); 
if (preg_match('{image/(.*)}is', $info['mime'], $p)) { 
  $name = "$imgDir/".time().".".$p[1]; 
  move_uploaded_file($tmp, $name);
}

}
}
```

И есть код, который накладывает водяной знак на фото:

```
$sOrigImg = "style/1.jpg"; //оригинал изображения
$sWmImg = "1.png"; //водяной знак

$aImgInfo = getimagesize($sOrigImg);
$aWmImgInfo = getimagesize($sWmImg);
if (is_array($aImgInfo) && count($aImgInfo)) {
    header ("Content-type: image/png");

    $iSrcWidth = $aImgInfo[0];
    $iSrcHeight = $aImgInfo[1];


    $rImage = imagecreatetruecolor($iSrcWidth+$iFrameSize*2, $iSrcHeight+$iFrameSize*2); // Создаем новое изображение
    $rSrcImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($sOrigImg); //  Создаем исходное изображение


    imagecopy($rImage, $rSrcImage, $iFrameSize, $iFrameSize, 0, 0, $iSrcWidth, $iSrcHeight); // Копируем полученное изображение на изображение-источник

    if (is_array($aWmImgInfo) && count($aWmImgInfo)) {
        $rWmImage = imagecreatefrompng($sWmImg); //  Создаем изображение водяного знака
        imagecopy($rImage, $rWmImage, $iSrcWidth-$aWmImgInfo[0], $iFrameSize, 0, 0, $aWmImgInfo[0], $aWmImgInfo[1]); // Копируем изображение водяного знака на изображение источник
    }


    imagepng($rImage); // Выводим изображение
```

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы этот водяной знак добавлялся на изображение при его загрузке на сервер. Чтобы оно сохранялось с водяным знаком?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (@$_REQUEST['Upload']) { 
$imgDir = '/images'; // директория для картинок
$data = $_FILES['file']; 
$tmp = $data['tmp_name']; 
if (@file_exists($tmp)) { 
$info = @getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); 
if (preg_match('{image/(.*)}is', $info['mime'], $p)) { 
$name = "$imgDir/".time().".".$p[1]; 
move_uploaded_file($tmp, $name);
$sOrigImg = $name; //оригинал изображения
$sWmImg = "1.png"; //водяной знак
$aImgInfo = getimagesize($sOrigImg);
$aWmImgInfo = getimagesize($sWmImg);
if (is_array($aImgInfo) && count($aImgInfo)) {
header ("Content-type: image/png");
$iSrcWidth = $aImgInfo[0];
$iSrcHeight = $aImgInfo[1];
$rImage = imagecreatetruecolor($iSrcWidth+$iFrameSize*2, $iSrcHeight+$iFrameSize*2); // Создаем новое изображение
$rSrcImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($sOrigImg); //  Создаем исходное изображение
imagecopy($rImage, $rSrcImage, $iFrameSize, $iFrameSize, 0, 0, $iSrcWidth, $iSrcHeight); // Копируем полученное изображение на изображение-источник
if (is_array($aWmImgInfo) && count($aWmImgInfo)) {
$rWmImage = imagecreatefrompng($sWmImg); //  Создаем изображение водяного знака
imagecopy($rImage, $rWmImage, $iSrcWidth-$aWmImgInfo[0], $iFrameSize, 0, 0, $aWmImgInfo[0], $aWmImgInfo[1]); // Копируем изображение водяного знака на изображение источник
}
imagepng($rImage); // Выводим изображение
}
}
}
```

Comment: появляется ошибка `Notice: Undefined variable: iFrameSize`